# Connecting MongoDB from localhost

Tags: python, pymongo, ssh-tunnel, aws-documentdb

I have an EC2 instance (`EC2_VM`) where I can connect mongodb (`MONGO_HOST`)from

```
with sshtunnel.open_tunnel(
    (EC2_VM, 22),
    ssh_username="ec2-user",
    ssh_pkey=EC2_KEY,
    remote_bind_address=(MONGO_HOST, 27017),
    local_bind_address=("0.0.0.0", 27017),
) as tunnel:
    print(tunnel.local_bind_port)    

    # list database names
    client = MongoClient(
        "mongodb://%s:%s@%s" % (MONGO_USER, MONGO_PASSWORD, "127.0.0.1"),
        port=tunnel.local_bind_port,
    )
    names = client.list_database_names()
    print(names)
```

But I am getting below error. Any idea whats wrong here? It looks like it has set up the tunnel properly but cant seem to reach mongo still. TIA

```
  File "/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 269, in _select_servers_loop
    raise ServerSelectionTimeoutError(
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: 127.0.0.1:27017: timed out, Timeout: 30s, Topology Description: <TopologyDescription id: 6530a0a24577402c25f1997e, topology_type: Unknown, servers: [<ServerDescription ('127.0.0.1', 27017) server_type: Unknown, rtt: None, error=NetworkTimeout('127.0.0.1:27017: timed out')>]>
```

anyone who has docdb set up in aws, how do you guys connect to it from localhost? It works with MongoDB Compass because it provides the ssh tunnel option from GUI but when I am trying to do it via script using pymongo, it's not working

TIA

Comment: Are the EC2 instance and the Mongo host different machines?

Comment: @Quassnoi they are different but on the same VPC

Comment: Just to rule out the obvious: can you connect to mongo from the EC2 instances's shell? Can you set up the tunnel using an ssh client and connect using Compass or mongo shell from your laptop? Is `AllowTcpForwarding` set to yes on the EC2 instance?

Comment: @Quassnoi yes i can connect to mongo from ec2.

I can connect to mongo from localhost using compass.

mongo shell has the same error

Comment: When you are connecting using compass, are you setting up the tunnel in the compass settings or using an external ssh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed by supplying `directConnection=True` to `MongoClient`